# Alter ActiveX video player source using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, video, activex

Here's the ActiveX control that I have embedded in my webpage:

```
<object id="MediaPlayer1" 
        CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" 
        codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/ en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
        standby="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..."
        TYPE="application/x-oleobject"
        width="280"
        height="256">
<param name="fileName" value="/media/paul.avi">
<param name="animationatStart" value="true">
<param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
<param name="autoStart" value="false">
<param name="showControls" value="true">
<param name="Volume" value="-20">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2"
        pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"
        src="/media/paul.avi"
        name="MediaPlayer1"
        width=280
        height=256 
        autostart=1
        showcontrols=1
        volume=-20>
</object>
```

Is there a way for Javascript to control the value for `fileName` and the src for the `embed` tag? I used a method sort of like the one I need just for a normal html5 video, here it is:

```
function vidSwap(vidURL) {
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    myVideo.src = vidURL;
    myVideo.load();
    myVideo.play();
}
```

I'm pretty sure the `document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]` grabs the first `<video>` tag in the page, but if I'm trying to get something inside of the `<object>` tag would it be along the lines of `document.getElementsByTagName('param')[0]` and likewise with the `<embed>`: `document.getElementsByTagName('embed')[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

I did a little experimenting with the following, and it seems to work; just add an id to the embed-tag, look it up, and change whatever values you want:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<object id="MediaPlayer1" 
        CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" 
        codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/ 
                  en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
        standby="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..."
        TYPE="application/x-oleobject"
        width="280"
        height="256">
<param name="fileName" value="/media/paul.avi">
<param name="animationatStart" value="true">
<param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
<param name="autoStart" value="false">
<param name="showControls" value="true">
<param name="Volume" value="-20">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2"
      id="myEmbededTag"
      pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"
      src="/media/paul.avi"
      name="MediaPlayer1"
      width=280
      height=256 
      autostart=1
      showcontrols=1
      volume=-20>
</object>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Look up the ID, and get a ref. to it:
    var element = document.getElementById('myEmbededTag');
    alert(element.src);
    element.src = 'http://example.com/yourvideo.avi';
    alert(element.src);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update in response to the comment by febreezey below:**

It kind of depends on when you want to do this; say you just want to set the source and start the video when the page completes loading, then you could do something like this (replace the previous JavaScript-section with the following):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var element = document.getElementById('myEmbededTag');
        alert(element.src);
        element.src = 'http://www.rabiner.com/files/David_Rabiner.wmv';
        alert(element.src);
    }
</script>
```

(Note, I have no idea what the example video is about, I just picked up some totally random example-video...)

**Final update:**

I'm not sure this is the ideal/perfect way to solve your problem (feels a little crude), but you could probably do something like this:

```
<a href="#" 
 onclick="javascript:SetVid('http://www.rabiner.com/files/David_Rabiner.wmv');">
Click to set value
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var SetVid = function(videoUrl){
        var element = document.getElementById('myEmbededTag');
        alert(element.src);
        element.src = videoUrl;
        alert(element.src);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Okay it's successfully changing the src of `<embed>`, but is there a way to load the video into the player and begin playing using the same javascript?

Comment: Earlier, I just checked that you could access the value of "src". Now I made a little change to the script (see the update above) to make sure it actually loads a video, and that works in a fashion. Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Okay that works for me. Now let's say I have a GridView of values and links to other videos. I click on one and it runs the above javascript code and reloads the page, now playing the recently selected video. Is there a lot to change here in order to achieve that?

Comment: Updated again: This should reload the page, with the video source updated. PS, If you have several videos (that is, several embed-tags) on the same page, you could pass the ID of the Embed-tag to change as a second parameter to the function.

Comment: Okay I don't know if it's just me, but this reloads the page but not the player. I'll have the default Paul.avi playing when I start the page, but when I click on another video the only thing that changes is the URL to have a # at the end. I need the video to reload and begin playing the new one.